# I want to unblock my client's site and my production site from loading the assets from my own site

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, web-hosting

I enabled the hotlink protection link at cPanel, and added four URLs to allow access:

```
https://myown.com.br
https://myclientssite.com.br
http://localhost
http://localhost:1984
```

And I added the extensions to block direct access:

```
bmp,css,eot,gif,ico,jpeg,jpg,js,png,otf,ttf,webp,woff
```

And I enabled to allow direct requests.

The Apache configuration code, that is located at the folder `public_html`, looks like:

```
RewriteEngine on

<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://myclientssite.com.br/.*$                 [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://myclientssite.com.br$                    [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://myown.com.br/.*$                         [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://myown.com.br$                            [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://myclientssite.com.br/.*$                [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://myclientssite.com.br$                   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://myown.com.br/.*$                        [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://myown.com.br$                           [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://localhost/.*$                            [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://localhost$                               [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://localhost:1984/.*$                       [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://localhost:1984$                          [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(bmp|css|eot|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png|otf|ttf|webp|woff)$ -    [F,NC]
```

But these sites are still denied from loading these files. Until my own site also is bizarrely blocked. The same error 403 – Denied access.

Yes, I also added:

```
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject    eot
AddType application/x-font-woff          woff
AddType font/eot                        .eot
AddType font/otf                        .otf
AddType font/opentype                    otf
AddType font/truetype                    ttf
AddType font/ttf                        .ttf
AddType font/woff                       .woff
AddType font/woff2                       woff2

AddType image/bmp                       .bmp
AddType image/gif                       .gif .GIF
AddType image/x-icon                    .ico
AddType image/jpeg                      .jpeg .jpg .JPEG .JPG
AddType image/png                       .png .PNG
AddType image/svg+xml                    svg
AddType image/svg+xml                    svgz
AddType image/tiff                      .tiff .tif

AddType application/json                 .json
AddType 'text/css; charset=UTF-8'        css
AddType 'text/js; charset=UTF-8'         js

<FilesMatch ".(bmp|css|eot|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png|otf|ttf|webp|woff)">
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://myown.com.br"
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://myown.com.br"
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://myclientssite.com.br"
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://myclientssite.com.br"
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://localhost"
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://localhost"
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://localhost:1984"
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://localhost:1984"
</FilesMatch>
```

Only my own site is unblocked, but `myownclient.com.br`, `localhost` and `localhost:1984` are still blocked.

### Update

Only the first two CSS files are blocked from opening, but all other CSS files are still unblocked from opening. All the JavaScript files also are still unblocked from opening.

I want to block **all** CSS and JavaScript files from opening.

Comment: Hey, you can check out my answer. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Does my answer work? Make sure to clear cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear cache. And try the following instead of that:

```
RewriteEngine on

<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?:\/\/(((www\.)?(myclientssite|myown)\.com\.br)|localhost(:1984)?)(\/.*)?$
RewriteRule .*\.(bmp|css|eot|gif|ico|jpe?g|js|png|(o|t)tf|webp|woff)$ - [F,NC]
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/P8Tsbh/1 and https://regex101.com/r/nXBWfT/1